# Disable .htaccess for a directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdirectory

Im using a Framework which has this .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.ico)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entryPoint.php [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

thats very good, because entryPoint.php runs everytime. But I have a PhpBB forum, placed in SITEROOT/forum directory. It would be the best that in this /forum directory to .htaccess be ignored. How to set a rule to be ignored in a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty with my rewrite rules but,

```
RewriteCond $1 !^/forum
```

Should work.

Comment: somebody posted "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/forum " this looks OK